# Bloquear caracteres especiais em <input matInput

Tags: angularjs, angular

Como faço para bloquear caracteres especiais em:

Eu tentei desta forma, mas realmente não funcionou:

pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Desde já agradeço !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu encontrei uma solução:

```
<input keypress="return String.fromCharCode(event.charCode).match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g) === null">
```

[RESPOSTA AQUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645034/how-do-i-block-special-caracters-in-input-matinput)